# match a short string within a long string in c++

Tags: c++, string, class

I tried to write a class called `Mystring` which basically does everything std::string class can do. Right now I'm trying to write a `MyString::rfind` function which will match a short string with the long string(just like the `rfind` function for string class). However, when I run the code nothing gets printed out in the console. Can anyone spot where the problem is?

```
//cpp 
size_t MyString::rfind(const MyString& str, size_t pos) const {
    if (str.size() == 0 && pos < s.size()) { return pos; }
    if (str.size() == 0 && pos > (s.size() - 1) ) { return s.size(); }
    size_t a = std::min(pos, (s.size() - 1));
    for (size_t i = a; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (s[a] == str.s[0]) {
            for (size_t b = 1; b < str.size(); ++b) {
                if (s[i + b] != str.s[b]) { break; }
                if (b == (str.size() - 1)) { return i; }
            }
            return -1;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}


//main
int main(){
 
const MyString testMyString = "0123456789";
cout << testMyString.rfind("647")<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your class doesn't have any constructor accepting a `const char*` so how does this compile?

Comment: *basically does everything std::string class can do.* -- No it cannot.  Note that `std::string` is a specialization of [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  So are you ready to implement all of those functions?

Comment: `s[i + b]` reads past the end of the array

Comment: You can also add an early exit if `pos + str.size() > s.size()`, which would mean you wouldn't need the `min` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here in the `rfind()` function:

```
for (size_t i = a; i >= 0; --i) {
```

The minimum value `size_t` can reach is `0`. If you decrement it when it is `0`, you wrap around to the largest value again. On my 64 bit system that value is `18446744073709551615`. As you can see this value is greater than `0` so the loop never finishes.

Try this piece of code and you will immediately see your mistake:

```
size_t x = 0;
x--;
cout << x; // What do you think it will print?
```

Comment: ok I see. It will print the biggest int. So all I need to do it to change `i >= 0` to `i>0`?

Comment: Yes, that will make it work. However, for the current code you will probably see `18446744073709551615` as output.

Comment: @Waqar Will that really work? Will it find a match at the beginning of the string, or stop before it gets there?

Comment: @Barmar Will it? I don't think so. The question was about being stuck in an infinite loop. And I answered about just that leaving the rest of the logic to OP. :)

Comment: So you fixed one bug but replaced it with a different bug? And didn't provide any insight about how to fix the new bug.

Comment: No. `i  > 0` will work,but there will need to be a few modifications.